# Separating HTML and PHP from the Script?

Tags: ajax, javascript

So I have this code which makes the infinite scrolling effect in WordPress.

It fetches the title and read more correctly.

The problem I find with this code is when I want to insert complex code that includes PHP, javascript and html.

Is it possible to separate HTML and PHP from the Script? Without writing in `postHtml`.

```
<div id="postContainer">
  <!-- Initial posts go here -->
</div>



    $(document).ready(function() {
  var page = 1; // Initial page number
  var isLoading = false; // Flag to prevent multiple simultaneous AJAX requests

  // Function to load more posts
  function loadMorePosts() {
    if (isLoading) return; // If a previous request is still in progress, do nothing

    isLoading = true; // Set the flag to indicate that a new request is being made

    // Send an AJAX request to fetch more posts from the WordPress REST API
    $.ajax({
      url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
      type: 'GET',
      data: { page: page },
      success: function(response) {
        // Process the response and append new posts to the container
        var posts = response; // Assuming the response contains a list of posts
        var postContainer = $('#postContainer');

        if (posts.length > 0) {
          // Append new posts to the container
          for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
            var postHtml = '<div class="post">' +
              '<h2>' + posts[i].title.rendered + '</h2>' +
              '<p>' + posts[i].excerpt.rendered + '</p>' +
              '<a href="' + posts[i].link + '">Read More</a>' +
              '</div>';

            postContainer.append(postHtml);
          }

          page++; // Increment the page number for the next request
          isLoading = false; // Reset the flag
        } else {
          // No more posts available
          $(window).off('scroll'); // Disable the scroll event
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        // Handle error
        console.log('An error occurred');
        isLoading = false; // Reset the flag in case of an error
      }
    });
  }

  // Attach scroll event handler to implement infinite scrolling
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollPosition = $(window).scrollTop();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var documentHeight = $(document).height();

    // Check if user has scrolled near the bottom of the page
    if (scrollPosition >= documentHeight - windowHeight - 500) {
      loadMorePosts();
    }
  });

  // Initial load of posts
  loadMorePosts();
});
```

Comment: can you be more specific about the problems you're encountering? The ask you've made doesn't make much sense, and heavily implies a misunderstanding of how this all works. The closest I can figure out is maybe you're asking if you can move the javascript into a `.js` file? I see the HTML tags in your code block, but then it turns into javascript jQuery code without any `<script>` tags. If you have JS not mentioned here that operates on the HTML in the posts then that needs reapplying when you insert brand new HTML, that's not a WordPress or PHP problem though